# ODBC connection not open

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio, odbc

I recently sent some **working** code from my laptop to my desktop. Even though they are both using the same tech (Visual studio community 15 and SQL Server 14) I am unable to connect to my database on the desktop.

I've got an identical ODBC driver on both (and have tried various combinations on my desktop). Whilst controlling the connection from the ODBC to SQL Server it seems fine, but when I run my application from the debugger I receive this error:

> Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection Not Open
>
> SQLSTATE: 08003 Failed to connect

This is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        wcout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
}

int main() {

    SQLHENV env;
    SQLHDBC dbc;
    SQLHSTMT stmt;
    SQLRETURN ret;
    SQLSMALLINT columns;
    int row = 0;

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    /* We want ODBC 3 support */
    SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);

    /* Connect to the DSN */
    SQLDriverConnectW(dbc, NULL, L"DRIVER={SQL Server};ERA-PC-STUART\\JBK_DB;DATABASE=master;UID=geo;PWD=kalle123;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    /* Check for success */
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt))
    {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc);
        std::cout << "Failed to connect";
    }
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirectW(stmt, L"select salary from dbo.salary_table", SQL_NTS)) {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
    }
    else {
        int id;
        cout << "ID:" << endl;
        while (SQLFetch(stmt) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            SQLGetData(stmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
            cout << id << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned the code runs flawlessly on my laptop, but for some reason it won't work on the desktop - even though the ODBC connects.

Comment: Try to check the return value of `SQLDriverConnect` and fetch the error-information if establishing the connection does not succeed. Usually, those error-messages contain quite useful information to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @erg Isn't that exactly what I'm doing by sending dbc to cout?

Comment: no, on the line with `SQLDriverConnect` you do not check the return value. You should already get an `SQL_ERROR` there, and you can then feed the connection-handle to the error-function.

Comment: @era You mind showing me how to do it? Can't really figure it out...

Comment: Like `ret = SQLDriverConnectW(dbc, NULL, L"DRIVER={SQL Server};ERA-PC-STUART\\JBK_DB;DATABASE=master;UID=geo;PWD=kalle123;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE); if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) { show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that might have this issue in the future; ensure that the TCP/IP is enabled in your SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In my case the above was disabled and the "Server=" was missing in the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

This might be probably due to windows version problem. Your laptop might be running on 64-bit os and your desktop might be running on 32 bit os. Create a new DSN on your desktop using 32-bit odbc data source administrator and try again.There is nothing wrong with the code

Comment: I did think that could be a solution; looking at my ODBC on the laptop it shows that it's 32/64 bit, whilst on the desktop it's without bit.

However, I've tried running the 32-bit version of ODBC admin and neither of the times have it added the 64/32-bit stamp next to it. I've also attempted to run the application under SQL Server, Native Server and ODBC.

Using the 32-bit ODBC admin is done by using "Run" and (in my case) c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe right? Or am I missing anythign?